# Another word for "kisses" or "slightly touches" or "barely makes contact"

Tags: word-choice, geography

I'm specifically trying to find the perfect word for this phrase I'm adding to Wikipedia:

> Oman's Musandam peninsula *kisses* the gulf at the Strait of Hormuz.

But *kisses* really isn't the right word. To see how it barely touches the Persian Gulf, go here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musandam_Governorate (the Persian Gulf is the top-left-most body of water in the first image. It ends at the red peninsula I'm trying to describe.

*I'll add that I'd like to keep the phrase succinct - this will be for a map caption.*

Comment: I think "touches" may be the best choice in the situation you describe; if you were talking about one object barely touching another while in motion past it, you might uses "grazes" or "lightly brushes past," but "grazes" doesn't work especially well in describing the point of contact between two stationary objects.

Comment: It doesn't actually mean any of the things you listed, but I'd probably just say it _demarcates_ the gulf.

Comment: I wouldn't be so poetic in writing about geography. Travel, maybe.

Comment: @medica - Such a spoilsport. It would be amusing to use purple prose for geography.  Ancient writers did that kind of thing all the time.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *demarcates* is awesome! ...but in the context I'm trying to point out that Oman is barely one of the seven "Gulf States". I ended up with `meets` - I think @medica is probably right.

Comment: **pierces**....

Comment: In my opinion, the *existing* wording of the entry is already a perfect description: "...the Musandam peninsula **juts into** the Strait of Hormuz..." *All* the terms suggested here so far are less apt. 'Demarcates' is particularly unsuitable, since that is the term one would use for a terrestrial boundary **between named political or geographical entities**, not the contour of a peninsula projecting into a body of water. 'Kisses' is completely inappropriate for this kind of Wikipedia entry.

Comment: **Is trying to get on first base** with the gulf....

Comment: *joins*, *intersects*, *meets*, *brushes*, *connects*, *touches*.

Answer (score 1):

**Adjoin** - ad·join - verb

*be next to and joined with (a building, room, or piece of land).*

3rd person present form:

> **Oman's Musandam peninsula adjoins the gulf at the Strait of Hormuz.**

Answer (score -1):

How about:

Caress

Nudge

Tap

Or just, as you had described it yourself, "barely touches"...